# how to fix the gap between bars in chart graph for crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

[image]

I'm working with Crystal reports in .net.
I have a requirement to fix the gap between the bars so that it is always equal between all the bars.

Couldn't find any property to do it.
Need help how to do it.

Comment: One possible solution is to filter out the records where value = 0, from your list or array. This way you can ensure that only those records with a vertical bar will show up on your chart and they will be placed evenly. Also there are features to suppress zero values: https://khanrahim.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/suppress-zero-in-crystal-report/

Comment: there is no zero value in this ..

Comment: Can you post some sample data used to generate this graph? The first four or five items.

Comment: I don't think you can do it programmatically. You must adjust Overlap and Gap Width values from Chart Options in Preview Mode until the result fits you. How many fields have you used as data values? What is the reason of chart bar color changing in your image?

Comment: Can you show a snapshot including the x-axis, I think there are 0 values that have 0-height columns, which only show more gap between the next and prev columns

Answer (score 1):

Go to Chart Options (Right-click Chart in Preview Mode > Chart Options > Appearance tab > Decrease the Gap Width).

Comment: The version of crystal report being used on my workplace doesn't have this option of preview mode.
I saw it on few blog posts but this option is not available to me.